# jython zxJDBC: How to get a dictionary from a cursor?

Tags: jdbc, jython

I am using JDBC to connect my jython to a heterogeneous set of databases.
Using a cursor I get the rows in list form, and the cursor
also knows the metadata (cursor.description).

Usually you get a row as list as result of a query:

```
print resultlist(4)
```

And you have to know the order of the Columns in the schema beforehand.

How can I get something like

```
print resultset[CustomerName]
```

to print the name of a customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `dict_cursor` from this question: [Django Backend-neutral DictCursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678991/django-backend-neutral-dictcursor)?

Outline of what works for me (Jython 2.5.2):

```
def dict_cursor(cursor):
    description = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor:
        yield dict(zip(description, row))

conn = zxJDBC.connect(db, user, pwd, driver)
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "..."
cursor.execute(query)

dc = dict_cursor(cursor)
for d in dc:
    print d["SomeColumnName"]
    ...

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Wow a needy one. You are gonna get disappointed a lot. But not by me. I have learnt something from your answer so +1. Have to test it before accepting it, though. Thx for the reminder.

Comment: Wow, a snarky one. Thank you.